# Docker expose ports between containers

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

I would like to have a python flask application that runs with a postgresql database (psycopg2). So I made this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - database
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "docker/Dockerfile.web"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - database:/var/run/postgresql
  database:
    container_name: database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_DB: "products"
    image: postgres
    expose:
    - 5432
    volumes:
    - database:/var/run/postgresql
volumes:
  database:
```

In my app.py I try to connect to postgres like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="products", user="user", password="password", host="database", port="5432")
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:
"*Is the server running on host "database" (172.21.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?*"

I don't know where I have mistaken here.

- The container "database" exposes its port 5432.
- Both containers are on the same network which is "web_app_default".
- The socket file existes in `/var/run/postgresql` directory on "web" container.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for replies and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what happened is that even though you have the flag `depends_on` set to `database`, that only means that the `web` container will start after `database` container starts. However, for the first time, the database will generally take quite some time to set up and when your `web` server is up, the database is still not ready to accept the connection.

2 ways to work around the problem here:

1. Easy way with no change in code: run `docker-compose up -d` (`detach` mode) and wait for the database to finish initializing. Then run `docker-compose up -d` again and your `web` container will now be able to connect to the database.
2. Second way is to update the `web` container with `restart: always` so `docker-compose` will keep trying to restart your `web` container until it runs successfully (until the database is ready to accept connection)

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    depends_on:
      - database
    ...
    restart: always
    ...
```